# Como inserir um objeto logo após o elemento da iteração no for of do javascript

Tags: javascript

Tenho um `array` que preciso varrer com o `for` `of` do javascript e preciso verificar se meu elemento atual tem o `id == 2` se tiver, preciso clona-lo e coloca-lo logo após o elemento atual.
Exemplo:

```
let data = [{id: 1}, {id: 2}, {id: 3}]
for (const dat of data) {
   if (dat.id == 2) {
      // quero inserir entre id 2 e id 3 um clone do meu elemento atual 
      // que no caso é o 2
   }
}

// Resultado esperado
[{id: 1}, {id: 2}, {id: 2}, {id: 3}]
```

É possivel? ou sera que é melhor criar um array auxiliar e gravar nele?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pode usar o [findIndex](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex) para encontrar o índice desejado, depois clonar e adicionar na posição a seguir usando [splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice):

```js
let data = [{id: 1}, {id: 2}, {id: 3}];
let idProcurado = 2;

// encontra o índice desejado
let indice = data.findIndex(function(elemento) {
   return elemento.id == idProcurado;
});

// se encontrou
if (indice > 0) {
   // clona um novo objeto e adiciona na posição a seguir
   let obj = { id: data[indice].id };
   // poderia usar var obj=data[indice]; mas isso não iria clonar e sim apontar para o mesmo objeto
   data.splice(indice+1, 0, obj);
}

console.log(data);
```